# Fail to update gitlab CICD variable using gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am exploring Gitlab APIs to work with CICD. For updating gitlab CICD variable, I use following API

```
PUT /projects/:id/variables/:key
```

[here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable) is the document regarding it. This API works perfect if the variable is unique for CICD. But If I use duplicate name variable with different environment_scope, it some time update my variable but most time fail to update. It throws following error

```
key: [MY_KEY] has already been taken
```

I checked in gitlab issues [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24029) but didn't found any proper solution regarding it.
For reference, my gitlab version is **GitLab Community Edition 12.8.1**

Can anybody help me regarding this?.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [found here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable), It appers you need to amend the follow to the end of the line:

```
--form "value=updated value"
```

So ultimately you will have:

```
PUT /projects/:id/variables/:key --form "value=updated value"
```

Comment: Hi @The Letter M ..thanks for answering. But this will not solve my issue. In actual use, I send the value as well as environment_scope. I provided above API just for reference. There may be issue in gitlab for updating duplicate variables with different scopes.